# N1QL query not working for one instance but works for other

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm having trouble querying anything but couchmusic1.country documents.
Here's how it looks like: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIS8u.png)

So, if I do

```
select * from couchmusic1.country limit 1;
```

it's fine, but if I do this:

```
select * from couchmusic1.playlist limit 1; //or any other number
```

I get empty results like this:

```
"results": [
    ],
    "status": "success".....................
```

Did anyone had similar issue? All documents are there, I've tried deleting primary index (only one so far) and recreating it, same.
Does someone knows why?

**EDIT:** The problem occur only when I have **LIMIT** parameter in query... I apologize for forgetting to mention it first time.

**EDIT2:** If someone is interested, this can be used as workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM couchmusic1 WHERE playlist IS NOT MISSING limit 1;
```

NOTICE: to see document structure, look at the image in the link above.

Comment: Can you try "select * from couchmusic1" and "select playlist from couchmusic1".

Comment: select * from couchmusic1; and select country from couchmusic1; returns document(s), but select playlist from couchmusic1; returns empty.

Comment: I stand corrected. "select playlist from couchmusic1;" and "select * from couchmusic1.playlist;" works. Problem is only when I put "limit" parameter. I'll edit the question. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, got it. This is a bug. If you have LIMIT, you have to use SELECT playlist FROM couchmusic1 LIMIT... This is only until we fix the bug. Sorry about that.

Comment: Great. Can you just put it in an answer, in case someone got the same issue and finds this? Thanks for your fast reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have hit upon a bug. If you have LIMIT in your query, you have to use

```
SELECT playlist FROM couchmusic1 LIMIT...
```

This is only until we fix the bug. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not working I tested on  Version: 4.1.0-5005 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Correct. The fix is in 4.5 DP.